# What would be a comprehensive method to register when a product stock level changes - Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, inventory, msi, magento24

We are having some issues with products going **out of stock** inexplicably,
We need to create a Magento module that registers whenever the product stock changes, such as API `updates`, `product sales` etc.

What would be a good way to hook into any and all stock-level changes so we can send an email?